# RPI 3 A+ weird behavior when no usb device connected

Tags: usb, boot, node.js, chromium

I have a RPI 3 A+ running a nodejs server that reads a I2C TH sensor and displays an UI with chromium on the official 7 inch display. The node server runs forever with PM2 and the browser runs in kiosk mode when boot.

The problem is chromium takes over 4 minutes to start. As a solution I replaced it by Firefox, which takes 20 second. Yesterday I realized that Chrome take 20 second too if there is a USB device connected (mouse or keyboard).  If no USB device is connected, chrome gets stuck and doesn't start for a long time.

I made several tests, I can confirm this behavior.

Btw. when I said chrome I meant Chromium. I test with chrome, vivaldi , firefox, epiphany, and others, the problem came with chromium, and vivaldi. Recently I disable serial interface and the delay increase over 10 minutes.

What could I do? 
This have even any sense?
Any suggestion?

Video showing the problem: https://youtu.be/5_L_HWTFw0k
The screen looks black because i deleted the desktop

Comment: Do you try to use three browser, chromium, chrome and firefox? What's about chromium? Does it still takes over 4 minutes to start?

Comment: yes, btw whe n i said chrome I meant Chromium. I test with chrome, vivaldi , firefox, epiphany, and others, the problem came with chromium, and vivaldi. Recently I disable serial interface and the delay increase over 10 minutes.

Comment: I added a video of the situation